# Why debug is not worked in java 11?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, docker, debugging

****This is using my Dockerfile****

```
FROM lpicanco/java11-alpine
VOLUME /tmp
ADD knetconfig /tmp/knetconfig
ADD grpc_health_probe_linux_x64 /app/grpc_health_probe_linux_x64
RUN chmod +x /app/grpc_health_probe_linux_x64
ADD aero-pay-core-service-latest.jar app.jar
RUN sh -c 'touch /app.jar'
EXPOSE 5005
ENV JAVA_OPTS="-agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=n,address=5005 -Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/./urandom"
ENTRYPOINT java $JAVA_OPTS -jar /app.jar
```

**But it getting this error in building time,I am using java 11,**

```
Error occurred during initialization of VM
Could not find agent library jdwp on the library path, with error: libjdwp.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

What would be the best possible options?

Comment: Have you tried an official JDK11 image instead of some random one? Like the Temurin one `eclipse-temurin:11-alpine`.

Comment: I think it’s because you’re adding $JAVA_OPTS in the ENTRYPOINT directive. JAVA_OPTS environment variable is read by java automatically.

Answer (score 1):

It may be that the alpine version of JDK11 is tuned to minimize the footprint.
Likely a debugging library was removed or never installed.